# Compatibilidad de los navegadores

Tags: html, css, navegador-web

me ocurrió algo que no sabía que podía pasar, cree un formulario vinculado a mysql, ese no es el punto, lo que pasa es cuando le das enviar, debe aparecer un mensaje arriba en la pantalla, y en el archivo .css le doy sus estilos correspondientes, pero, cuando abro mi archivo en google, el mensaje se muestra correctamente arriba de la pantalla, pero en el navegador Microsoft Edge no se le aplican los estilos, cabe recalcar que todo lo demás de la pagina funciona al 100.

Les agradecería mucho si me pueden explicar porque pasa eso, saludos.

Comment: Debes agregar a tu pregunta un [MCVE] con el código suficiente para reproducir el problema (HTML+CSS), el código debe ser mínimo, en tu caso solo lo correspondiente al mensaje. Además ayudaría una fotos que mostrará como se ve en ambos casos